# Eclipse Mars/Neon Marketplace crashes in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, gtk, ubuntu-12.04

When I click on Help -> Eclipse Marketplace, eclipse freezes or crashes with the error

```
java: /build/oxygen-gtk3-CbjxkW/oxygen-gtk3-1.0.2/src/animations/oxygencomboboxdata.cpp:87: void Oxygen::ComboBoxData::setButton(GtkWidget*): Assertion `!_button._widget' failed.
```

Neither setting SWT_GTK3=0 nor adding

```
-launcher.GTK_version
2
```

before

```
--launcher.appendVmargs
```

in eclipse.ini solves the problem.

This happens both for Mars and the latest Neon RC1 release. Did anyone experience this as well and knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

[Comment 20 of eclipse bug report 440660](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=440660#c20) solves it for me. Note that I had to set SWT_GTK3=0 to make sure GTK 3 is not used.

Answer (score 1):

*Markus last comment is right*. As in the comment in the bug:
Edit the file `/usr/share/themes/oxygen-gtk/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`

From:

```
GtkComboBox::appears-as-list = 1
```

To:

```
GtkComboBox::appears-as-list = 0
```

This was enough to fix it for me. I didn't need to set `SWT_GTK` as Markus suggested.

I'm running **Linux Mint 17.3** so you'll likely see this with **Ubuntu 14.04** as well.

Comment: nice, but even with this change I have to start via `SWT_GTK3=0 ./eclipse` 
. Only then I get rid of the error. Think I shall upgrade my Ubuntu 12.04 system  - but never find the time . Thx